# SAS variable has no type

Tags: types, sas

I have a database I import through a PROC SQL step in a program in SAS EG 5.1

Originally the code I used to do this was as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE WORK.TABLE AS 
     SELECT * FROM connection to some_source (
     SELECT *
     FROM some_table
     WHERE LOGIN_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM WORK.ID_List);;
```

This generated the error: "Expression using IN has components that are of different data types."

These should both be numeric (I *know* that `ID` is numeric) but I assumed that `LOGIN_ID` must be represented as character and resolved to convert it to numeric in this step. I fumbled around google for quite a while trying to find a way to do this until a colleague told me it cannot be done in this step unless I list out all 40 columns and use `AS`, which is going to be a last resort. I'm not sure if he's correct.

So I deleted the `WHERE` clause to get a look at the data. It all looks fine, and `LOGIN_ID` certainly looks numeric, so I tried using `VTYPE` to check its type. What I got is a column of null values (dots). Again, google was no help here.

So, how can these numbers not have a type? Also, any ideas about how to solve the original problem are greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you using `vtype`?  In a data step?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you're using `vtype()`? Is it something like `x = vtype(login_id);` then you look at `x` in the resultant dataset? Do you have any log messages?

Comment: yes, that's exactly the way

Comment: If `vtype` is returning dots/null then it's because you're returning it to a numeric column.  `vtype` returns character type.

Comment: @Joe is right on the money. Try `length x $ 100; x = vtype(login_id);` to ensure you're getting the expected result from `vtype()`.

Comment: You could always use `proc contents`, of course, to find out the answer as well.  Some of this might have slightly variable results if you're using `ds2` or a RDBMS connected via libname, but ultimately it *should* always return a 'C' or 'N'.

Comment: Just a comment about listing all variables, you can cheat by using DESCRIBE in your initial PROC SQL statement that will list out all variables in the log.

Comment: @Reese: That's not cheating--that's a good idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
create table work.table as
select a.*
from connection to some_source (
    select *
    from some_table
) as a
inner join work.id_list as b
on cats(a.login_id) = cats(b.id);
```

The SQL query passed to the connection has to be valid in the host database system, so it's a good idea to avoid referencing SAS tables from within that query. To get the result you're hoping for with the `in` operator, you can `inner join` on your SAS dataset.

The `cats()` function blindly casts its argument to a character string and removes and leading and trailing blanks. So if `login_id` and `id` are not of the same type, this will ensure that they can still be matched appropriately. Note that missing numeric values will become `"."` and missing character values will become `""`, so it's a good idea to know whether you have missing values in either column on which you're joining.

You only need to list all of the columns rather than using `select *` if you want to explicitly change the type in the connection query. The method above will avoid having to do that.

Comment: The colleague is focusing solely on changing the type of `login_id`, which does require removing the `*`.  The other way (how you do it, or similar) is right.

Comment: I'd also note that you can keep the inner query, and use it similar to above: `where login_id in (select put(id,8.) from work.id_list)` or similar (or use `cats`, though I personally thing `put` is more correct - `cats` will use default `best12.` format which is occasionally dangerous for long IDs).

Comment: @Joe: Thanks, I seemed to have missed the point about changing the type of `login_id` directly in the `select`. I was kind of confused as to why the colleague thought that was the way to go. :P

Comment: This seems to have worked. I'm still not sure how to explain the other anomaly, but I'm very gratified that you provided me with this answer. Thanks and good day! Also, I did try put earlier with no success ... can't remember the error message at the moment

Comment: @Rookatu: I'm glad this worked for you. To investigate the other anomaly, try out some of the stuff suggested in comments on the original post. Happy new year!

Comment: put -> character, input -> numeric; you may have used the wrong one.